# Why doesn't change $w("#input1").value when I click button? (Wix site code)

Tags: input, textbox, between, velo

https://russian-dima.wixsite.com/wixworld/nedvizhimost-iiii this site is exactly I'm trying to create. I coded all dropdowns but price filter code doesn't work. I don't know why!

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';
export function button14_click(event) {
    $w.onReady(function () {
        let min = Number($w("#input1").value)
        let max = Number($w("#input2").value)

        $w("#dataset1").setFilter(wixData.filter().between("fiyat", min, max))

            .then((results) => {
                console.log("Dataset is now filtered");
                $w('#propertyList').data = results.items;
            });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is there an `onReady` in there? I would guess that is your problem.